# ros2 parameter setting

Tags: ros, ros2

I would like to follow a simple take off and land example without any launch files or yaml files on [**ros2 crazyswarm**](https://imrclab.github.io/crazyswarm2/usage.html) (**Physical Experiments part**). What could be the reason for the following output, thanks.

```
ntukenmez3@ae-icps-407120:~/Documents/ros2_ws$ ros2 param set crazyflie_server cf231.params.commander.enHighLevel 1
Setting parameter failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you set up correctly the `crazyflies.yaml` file: [link](https://imrclab.github.io/crazyswarm2/usage.html#crazyflies-yaml)